# I try to figure out how to write a program, when I press the button on top and display some information on the bottom panel

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class InitialPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private JButton but;
    TopPanel top= new TopPanel();
    BottomPanel bot = new BottomPanel();
    public InitialPanel(){
        super();
        setBackground(Color.gray);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        top.getDisplayPosition().addActionListener(this);


    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        String a=top.getFp1().getPosition();
        but=new JButton(a);
        bot.setB1(but);  
        add(bot, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }
}
```

here is the code, the top panel will have a button and when I press it, It should change the information in the button for bottom panel and display it. But I cannot make the bottom panel change

Comment: I don't see your question here, you haven't told the problem just asking people to do your work

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

> But I cannot make the bottom panel change

When you add/remove components from a panel the basic structure is:

```
panel.add(....);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

The revalidate() will invoke the layout manager otherwise the newly added component has a size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.